# GAE3 Python and validating firebase token server side (do we need to call Firebase everytime?)

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

This is my first GAE app so please let me know if my approach is wrong. I have knowledge of Flask and have used Flask-Login before for my authentication needs. With GAE, it seems they suggest to use Firebase. Mine is not a SPA but I wanted to use Firebase UI and let it handle all the user authentication part.

Looking at the examples here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python3/building-an-app/building-an-app-3/static/script.js#L42 , i can verify the token server side using the Python Admin SDK. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#python or a more developed example https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#python . I am able to do this but I am a bit confused about the flow later on.

In the same example, they suggest to store the token (or some part of claims) as secured cookie. This is similar to how Flask Login also stores the cookie and then we verify the cookie in every request - but since in the case the backend is local REDIS or any storage, the validation is not expensive. But when using Firebase, it seems we will have to call Firebase for every api call to validate the token.

Otherwise, it could that be that user has changed their password or reset something in their Google/Facebook provider and we wont know at our server till we validate things at the provider end. This also prevents us from developing locally offline (or we write some logic to specially handle local development).

Whats the best way to solve this?

Comment: Hello, you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to manage users or to manage authentication tokens, according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin)

Comment: Correct. So that I understood from reading the admin docs. What I am worried about is that for every API call in our app or page load, i have to do a firebase call so that could become expensive. If thats the suggested way, then I guess I can just do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK to manage users or to manage authentication tokens, [according to the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) – marian.vladoi